# PHP - Multiple OR operators in if statement

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, logical-operators

I am working with getters and setters within my Symfony project. I have to use `if()` statement to check if status field does not have specific values before changing other field.

Code:

```
const STATUS_FAILED = 'failed';
const STATUS_PROGRESS = 'progress';
const STATUS_DELETED = 'deleted';

if ($entity->getStatus() !== Entitiy::STATUS_FAILED || 
    $entity->getStatus() !== Entitiy::STATUS_PROGRESS || 
    $entity->getStatus() !== Entitiy::STATUS_DELETED) 
    {
        $entity->setPreviousStatus($entity->getStatus());
    }
```

I defined constants and also using `OR` operator. I was wondering if there is more elegant solution than this. Maybe `is_array()` function, but don't know can it be used in this contest?

Comment: You could use an `in_array` instead

Comment: your OR statement is always true, you should use AND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do something like this

```
 $allowed = [self::STATUS_DELETED, self::STATUS_PROGRESS, self::STATUS_FAILED];
 if(!in_array($entity->getStatus(), $allowed)) {
     $entity->setPreviousStatus($entity->getStatus());
 }
```

Passing your **constants** in an array and the check if you status is **in_array**.

Comment: Might want to suggest using the optional true strict checking of in_array, since without it, depending on $entitiy->getStatus() return type, weird things could happen. See official [php.net in_array documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#106319)

Comment: I guess ->getStatus() can only have his constants, but yes, if not, adding a true parameter could be useful